# php email automatically displays notification even if i just opened my site

Tags: php, notifications

I'm just beginner when it comes to coding, don't judge.

I wanted to display a notification after I clicked the submit button or to display a notification if there is something wrong with the data I input with the form. But it seems that the notification was already displayed even if I just opened the file.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "Customer Inquiry";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);

        echo " Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else { 
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
?>
```

Here's the form:

```
<div class="column">
    <h3>Get in Touch</h3>
    <form action="#" target="myIframe" id="contactUs" method="post">

        <div class="field half first">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message">
    </form>
    <?php include "mailer.php"?>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's not a POST request you should just display the form, not return an error.

Comment: I wanted to display the form yet it returns the error already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because of the `else` block at the end. When you're displaying the form it's a `GET` request, not `POST`, so the `if` condition is false. That shouldn't be treated as an error, you should just display the form when that happens.

Get rid of

```
 else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

Comment: It worked! But I am getting another tab opened when I click the button

Comment: Do you have an `<iframe id="myIframe">` element in the HTML? If not, `target="myIframe"` causes a new tab or window to be opened.

Comment: I got the idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

You should have

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

`isset($_POST['submit'])` checks whether the form is submitted or not.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error and the button opens another tab when I used that.